# C# async processing and multithreading error

Tags: c#, multithreading, asynchronous, runtime-error

i am learning async processing , and i find `LongProcess()` can't access the `textbox1` of the main thread .

I have a button `button1` and a textbox `textbox1` .
I want to call `LongProcess` asynchronously.
 my code :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Threading;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Async
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        public void LongProcess()
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 1500; i++)
            {
                textBox1.Text += "/-------/" + i;
            }
            if (textBox1.Text != "")
            {
                textBox1.Text += "/////////////";
            }
        }

        public Task CallProcess()
        {
            return Task.Run(() =>
            {
                LongProcess();
            });
        }

        private async void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            await CallProcess();
        }

        private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

When i run click the button , i get an error :

> System.InvalidOperationException: '跨執行緒作業無效: 存取控制項 'textBox1' 時所使用的執行緒與建立控制項的執行緒不同。'

Sorry , the language of my OS is chinese .

How can i fix this error ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The UI must be updated using the UI thread. Since you are updating a UI element (i.e. `textBox1`), you need to use the appropriate thread. In WPF this can be done via the [`Dispatcher`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatcher(v=vs.110).aspx) class or in WinForms via the `Invoke` or `BeginInvoke` functions from the [`Control`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control(v=vs.110).aspx) class. I highly recommend getting acquainted with the [Async/Await model](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt674882.aspx) and [best practices](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx).